# Adding Task to executor

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have coded an inner class CreateRecord for creating a Record instance.It is later submitted as a task to the executor when create method is invoked.
Do I have to make an inner classes every time to represent the task to be performed(e.g deleteRecord,updateRecord) .
Could anyone suggest a better way.

```
 ExecutorService exec=new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize,maxPoolSize,
         keepAlive,TimeUnit.MINUTES,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

    public void create(String str ) throws RemoteException
    {
      exec.execute(new CreateRecord(str));
    }

    class CreateRecord implements Runnable
    {
      private String Id;
      public  CreateRecord(String Id)
      {
        this.Id=Id;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() 
      {

        System.out.println("Record creation in progress of: "+Id+
              " by thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Record rec=new Record(Id);
        map.put(Id, rec);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just instantiate a `Runnable` instead of declaring a new class. These are called anonymous inner classes in Java.

```
public void create(final String id) throws RemoteException
{
    exec.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            System.out.println("Record creation in progress of: "+id+" by thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Record rec=new Record(id);
            map.put(id, rec);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ExecutorService` requires a `Runnable` object. A `Runnable` object must be an instance of a class.

Two options:

(1) Parameterize your `Runnable` class to be able to do more than one thing. But this violates some good design principles.

(2) Use an anonymous class:

```
public void create(final String id) throws RemoteException {
    exec.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Record creation in progress of: "+id+" by thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Record rec = new Record(id);
            map.put(id, rec);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that `id` and any other variables you want to use from outside the `Runnable` must be declared `final`.

FYI,

```
System.out.printf(
    "Record creation in progress of: %d by thread: %s%n",
    id,
    Thread.currentThread().getName()
);
```

is a bit more legible.

Answer (score -1):

Have a single class like you do now, say `Record`, and specify an additional `int` or `String` argument in the constructor, which can be used in the `run()` method to decide what to do - i.e. update, delete or add a record, depending on the value of this second argument. Something like this:

```
class Record implements Runnable
{
  private String id;
  private String operation;
  public  Record(String id, String operation)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.operation = operation;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() 
  {
      if(operation.equals("update")) {
          //code for updating
      } else if(operation.equals("insert")) {
          System.out.println("Record creation in progress of: "+Id+
                  " by thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Record rec=new Record(id);
            map.put(id, rec);
      } else {//if(operation.equals("delete"))
          map.remove(id);
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really like the idea of a [stringly typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Would be better to have operation be of type Enum where the Enum was UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE and use a switch statement.